Limit through definition
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2}=0$$
I did the following steps:

$\left|\frac{1}{2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2}\right|<\varepsilon$


$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2<-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$

$\log_2({2+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}})<\frac{2}{x}<\log_2({2-\frac{1}{\epsilon}})$

$\dfrac{2}{\log_2({2-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}})}<x<\dfrac{2}{\log_2({2+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}})}$


Where am I wrong? This is not in an interval of zero.

In the second step you don't get a chain of inequalities. What you get is $\frac{1}{\epsilon}<2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2$ $\textbf{or}$ $2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. So you have two cases.

But it doesn't change my problem, above all with $\log_{2}(2-\frac{1}{\epsilon})$

Examine the case. Can it actually happen that $2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ when $x$ is very small (and positive)?

No, because the logarithm doesn't exist in that case. But actually what it matters to me is the other case because I have 0+. But is $x<\dfrac{2}{\log_2({2+\frac{1}{\epsilon}})}$ an interval of 0+? Shouldn't it be x bigger than that?

What you need t find is a $\delta$ s.t. whenever $x<\delta$ you have $\left|\frac{1}{2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2}\right|<\epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon$. And you just found your $\delta$.

Also the logic there is a bit backwards. It's not that the case can't happen because the logarithm doesn't exist. That would just mean that you can't apply the logarithm here. It cant happen because $2^{\frac{2}{x}}$ get's very big when $x$ gets small.

So it can't be smaller that a negative number. But the other part is right, right?

Sure. You should check the limit definition again. You found that for $\delta=\dfrac{2}{\log_2({2+\frac{1}{\epsilon}})}$ the definition is satisfied.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Since we are dealing with a limit to $x\to 0^+$, we can assume $0<x<2$ such that
$$\left|\frac{1}{2^{\frac{2}{x}}-2}\right|<\varepsilon \iff 2^{\frac2x}>2+\frac1\varepsilon \iff \frac2x>\frac{\log\left(2+\frac1\varepsilon \right)}{\log 2}\iff x<\frac{2\log 2}{\log\left(2+\frac1\varepsilon \right)}$$
and this works for $\varepsilon<\frac12 $ otherwise it suffices to take $x=1$, therefore according to the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition we have $\delta =\min\left(\frac{2\log 2}{\log\left(2+\frac1\varepsilon \right)};1\right)$.

Note that, Since we are dealing with a limit to $x\to 0^+$, we can also restric our analysis to $0<x<1$ such that $\delta =\frac{2\log 2}{\log\left(2+\frac1\varepsilon \right)}$ which is a perfectly fine solution.
